# apache not dumping core at folder specified with CoreDumpDirectory directive

Tags: apache

I have tried following things:

1. CoreDumpDirectory /abc in httpd.conf file
2. chown user:group abc 
   chmod 777 abc
3. sysctl -w fs.suid_dumpable=2
4. sysctl -w kernel.core_pattern=/abc
5. ulimit -c gave me unlimited

but I am still getting core dumps at /var/coredumps instead of /abc folder.

Any clue?

Comment: And what does 'ulimit -c' for that user show you (or what is set in login.conf) ?

Comment: Dirk, it says unlimited.

Comment: So you'll have to do a bit of a scan in places like /etc/login.conf, /etc/sysctl and so on - as something is clearly overwriting your setting.